# problems with starting tomcat 6 while tomcat 7 is running

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, struts

I am trying to deploy apps to different versions of tomcat.  Have 7 and 6 with jdk 1.7.0_02.  I have managed to start tomcat 7 using command line.  It functions OK.  Problem is when I try to run tomcat 6 (no change to environmental variables java_home and jre_home).  I got an error:

```
The Java_home environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: Java_home should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

how can I fix it so that I can operate both tomcat 6 and tomcat 7?

Comment: 6 might not recognise java 7, try pointing it to Java 6 (make sure you've got it installed somewhere as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the tomcat website, "While it is possible that older versions of Tomcat may not be compatible with newer JVMs, all the currently supported Apache Tomcat versions (5.5.x, 6.0.x and 7.0.x) are known to run correctly on Java 6 JVMs." So this means that tomcat 6 might not work with Java 7. You will need Java 6 installed as well.

So, before you run tomcat 6 using the command line, try using set path to set the path for the JDK bin directory for Java 6.

So, for instance if your JDK bin is at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin,

then try

```
        set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin;
```

and then run tomcat from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

> *"how can I fix .."*

The first step in fixing problems is to *read the error message*.

In this case, it tells you exactly what needs to be done.  Make sure that the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set to the path to your JDK installation; e.g. `C:\Program Files\jdk 1.7.0_02` ... or wherever it is that you've installed the JDK.

---

If you have problems getting Tomcat 6 to run on a Java 7 JDK (highly unlikely IMO), then you could install a Java 6 JDK and use that to run either or both of the Tomcats.  However, that shouldn't be necessary.  All indications are that Tomcat 6 should run *just fine* on a Java 7 JDK.

Comment: as I said tomcat 7 is using these environmental variables and it is set as you have written.  I also wondered whether it is need to downgrade to jdk 6 it was odd to me thus decided to ask this question.  Thought there should be some backward compatibility.